# With correct permissions for Microsoft Graph API, getting error: "Missing role permissions on the request"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

On the GET request:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/joinedTeams`

with the access token retrieved from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/4c3a1b30-xxxx-xxxx-9581-0281c4427992/oauth2/token

I am getting the error below.
I have provided all the permissions, see screenshot below.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Missing role permissions on the request. API requires one of 'Team.ReadBasic.All, TeamSettings.Read.All, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All, User.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All'. Roles on the request ''.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-12-20T16:34:51",
            "request-id": "f7972c62-00d2-44ed-840c-5c7fd19638a6",
            "client-request-id": "f7972c62-00d2-44ed-840c-5c7fd19638a6"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I am trying to get a response with details of Teams I joined. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

After spending sometime to test this, I am convinced that this is not an expected scenario.

1. You do not require all these permissions to successfully make this call. One of these is sufficient to return a response. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http (Adhering to principles of Zero Trust).
2. In the event that the access token was acquired prior to permission granting, it is necessary to initiate a new token request that encompasses the updated permissions.